# Python Alarm Clock code issue for raspberry pi project

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, clock, alarm

I've written this code for an the alarm clock portion of a project I am working on (coffee brewing alarm clock). When I run the program it either just skips to the "yikes..." portion or returns the error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'start'

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this fixed and the alarm clock working? I just need a fresh set of eyes as I am still new to python and have been looking at the code for too long now.

```python
import time
import os
import threading


class Alarm(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, hours, minutes):
        super(Alarm, self).__init__()
        self.hours = int(hours)
        self.minutes = int(minutes)
        self.keep_running = True

    def run(self):
        try:
            while self.keep_running:
                now = time.localtime()
                if (now.tm_hour == self.hours and now.tm_min == self.minutes):
                    print("ALARM NOW!")
                    os.popen("bensound-dubstep.mp3")
                    return
            time.sleep(60)
        except:
            return
    def just_die(self):
        self.keep_running = False



print("Enter your name: ")
user_input=input(":")

print("Hello, " + user_input)

alarm_HH = input("Enter the hour you want to wake up at: ")
alarm_MM = input("Enter the minute you want to wake up at: ")

print(("You want to wake up at: " + alarm_HH + ':' + alarm_MM).format(alarm_HH, alarm_MM))

alarm=("class Alarm")
class Alarm (Alarm(alarm_HH, alarm_MM)):
    alarm.start()

try:
    while True:
         text = str(user_input())
         if text == "stop":
            alarm.just_die()
            break

except:
    print("Yikes lets get out of here")
    alarm.just_die()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question title doesn't reveal too much about the problem you're having. Could you improve it? Also consider [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with that end loop, but i believe that the reason it is giving you that error is because you're trying to reference user_input as if it is a function. Maybe you were trying to just wait for the user to enter something? if so...

Try changing this:

```
text = str(user_input())
```

to this:

```
text = str(input(''))
```

Comment: Ok thanks. That kept the program from crashing but it now requires an return strike to activate "Alarm now!" and no sound plays. any ideas there?

Comment: and the thought for that end loop was just to give the user a way to close the program through a "stop" command